# How to add new column to Quotation tree view in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to add new column (a field from Partner model) to the Quotation tree view. This is the original tree view in debug mode

[image]

```
<tree string="Quotation" fonts="bold:message_unread==True" colors="grey:state=='cancel';blue:state in ('waiting_date','manual');red:state in ('invoice_except','shipping_except')">
                    <field name="message_unread" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="name" string="Quotation Number"/>
                    <field name="date_order"/>
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <field name="user_id"/>
                    <field name="amount_total" sum="Total Tax Included"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                    <field name="credit_limit"/>
                </tree>
```

Then I tried adding `<field name="credit_limit">` within the tree tag however it gives `Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!`.

Any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: Share your full code. With given information, we can not understand which object's view modify.

Comment: updated with extra information.

Comment: I am doing the above without touching any source code. Everything is done through OpenERP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Since you are adding field directly from the frontend
>
> You need to make field first follow these steps.
>
> Settings > Technical >  Database Structure > Fields > create field as per image and then try to add in tree view

and change field name in view *credit_limit* to *x_creditlimit*

[image]

This will work help you out!

Comment: Thats not the issue. I think I need to tell the xml that `credit_limit` field comes from which relation.

Comment: ok that means you have't declared in model (in .py file) directly trying to add from frontend!??

Comment: I am doing this without touching the .py file. Everything is done through OpenERP.

Comment: I thinks this is pretty close. The `credit_limit` field is already exist in `Partner` model. How can I call that field in my Quotation / Sales Order tree view ?

Comment: No it is not possible the way you want it!!

Answer (score 0):

We need to build new custom module for that or you can go with @Dexj answer.

Try with following code:

.py file with

```
from openerp.osv import osv

class Sales(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
        'credit_limit': fields.float('Credit Limit')
    }
```

view file which will add field

```
<record id="sale_order_credit_limit_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.credit.limit.form.view</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="state" position="after">
            <field name="credit_limit"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

now restart your server and update module list. You will get your new module and install it. You will see your desire output.

**EDIT**

In that case, we can use related field.

For example

```
_columns = {
    'credit_limit': fields.related('partner_id', 'credit_limit', type='float', string='Credit Limit')
}
```

Comment: the `credit_limit` belongs to `Partner` model. I don't see any partner model being referred in your code. Is that correct ? Also where do I key in the above code (for both .py file and xml) ?

Comment: You may refer following link https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html